# Javascript writing over previous value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I'm very new to javascript, and can't figure this seemingly simple issue. I have an array of elements (say usernames) that i iterate over. i want to map these usernames to click event methods (i know this isn't the perfect way, but it's just something that seems to work):

```
this.events = this.events || {};
var self = this;

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.user[i]);    // < --- this username is correct
    var username = data.user[i];
    $(this.el).append("<td><button class='btn btn-primary save" + i + " btn-sm'>Save</button></td>");

    var eventKeySave = 'click ' + '.save' + i;
    this.events[eventKeySave] = function(){
            (function (username) {
                console.log("inside method save " + username); // <--- this username is wrong
                self.onSave(username, 'something')
            })(username);
        };
}

this.delegateEvents();
```

now, in my `onSave` method, it just merely prints the usernames:

```
onSave: function(name, extras) {
    console.log("you clicked save on " + name + " , " + type); // < -- wrong name
}
```

But why do i ALWAYS get only the LAST username of the array in my `onSave` function?

for example, if my array looks like `[ 'david', 'emily', 'stephanie', 'michelle']`, only `michelle` gets passed in to the `onSave` function, despite the fact that each button's click event should have been set with the respective name in the array.

i even tried to pass the username by value but it still doesn't work. what is going on in Javascript that i'm not seeing?

Comment: Make your closure before assigning the event handler (not in the handler). If not the username will change before the event is fired, because the for-loop keeps on going and reassign the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a closure:

```
this.events[eventKeySave] = (function (name) {
    return function(){
        console.log("inside method save " + name); // <--- this username is now ok
        self.onSave(name, 'something');
    };
})(username);
```

It happens because the function is called after that the for loop ended, so the value of "username" is the last value of the array in all cases.
Add a closure save the actual value of 'username' for that returned function

Comment: ohhh. okay yeah, this was exactly it. that explains a bunch. thanks!!